# Linear algebra: Projections

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $P$, $Q:E\rightarrow E$, be projections and $PQ=QP$, show that $N(P)+N(Q)=N(PQ)$, $N(P)$ stands for Kernel of $P$

As $P$, $Q$ are projections and $PQ=QP$ then $PQ$ is a projection, so $E= N(PQ)\oplus \text{Im}(PQ)$
and also $E=N(P)\oplus \text{Im}(P)=N(Q)\oplus \text{Im}(Q)$. It's easy to see $N(P)+N(Q)\subset N(PQ)$
, but don't know how to arrive to the other inclusion or how to put $E=N(P)+N(Q)\oplus \mathrm{Im}(PQ)$ in that case the answer will follow immediately.

I've tried this last idea by writing $2v=(v-Pv)+(v-Qv)+(Pv+Qv)$ because $(v-Pv)+(v-Qv)$ is in $N(PQ)$ but then I can't conclude that Pv+Qv is in $\mathrm{Im}(PQ)$.

Any hint would be appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should provide a definition for the *nucleus* of a projection. It's what's more widely known as the *kernel*, isn't it?

Comment: Oh yes sorry you're right Nucleus is Kernel I'll edit it

Comment: Also, are you talking about orthogonal projections in Hilbert space?

Comment: @Rasmus: I think that the relations $P^2=P$, $Q^2=Q$ and $QP=PQ$ suffice. The first two (idempotency) relations mean that that the two endomorphisms are projections, and the last was given (and also implies that the composite mapping is an idempotent). No need to assume an inner product, I think.

Comment: @Rasmus the problem doesn't say something about the orthogonality of the projections

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $PQv=0$, then $v=v-PQv=(v-Pv)+(Pv-PQv)$. Here clearly $v-Pv$ is in the kernel of $P$. As $PQ=QP$, the latter term really is $(Pv-PQv)=(Pv)-Q(Pv)$, and this is in the kernel of $Q$. We have written an arbitrary vector annihilated by $PQ$ as a sum of a vector from $\mathrm{Ker}(P)$ and a vector from $\mathrm{Ker}(Q)$. Therefore the missing inclusion is proven.

Comment: Jyrki, could you please explain your last step, namely getting to $(v-Pv)+(Pv-PQv)$? Thanks

Comment: @InterestedGuest: Did you mean how to get $$v=v+0-0=v+(Pv-Pv)-PQv=(v-Pv)+(Pv-PQv)$$ or what? I simply subtracted a zero vector ($=PQv$), added and subtracted $Pv$, and did a bit of regrouping.

Comment: Oh I see, it makes sense now. :) Thanks